# Modules in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am working for a medical project, where i hold so many modules like..

Regisration
Login

There are 2 types of users in the system:

**Patient**
Profile
Patient history
Appointments (also in doctor)
Prescriptions
Lab Reports

**Doctor**
Schedules
Appointments (also in patient)
Create Hospital

Can i make every user as a module in zend framework 2, or creating a single module and make every other functionality(appointments, schedules) as a controller.

Can anyone guide me..

Comment: There are no rules regarding how many modules you can have or what the modules contain, my current project has *several* modules *per* user. You could have your entire application sitting in just one module or hundreds of them with just a single file, `Module.php`. It entirely depends on the project and if you have the time to write reusable, decoupled code.

Comment: I  plan to write a Module for each and every funcionality a module , like module for appointments, module for schedules etc. But my problem in this type  is can i use the namespace from one module to another module? Like calling the appointmentsAction()  from the scheduleAcion(), is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> As pointed out by AlexP in the comments this is not true at all.

<del>First off no you shouldn't create modules for each of these users. These pretty much just types of Users using your system. I.e User Roles.</del>

Now there various ways and modules that could achieve restrictions regarding those users I personally like [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize). This uses zendframeworks [ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html) implementation with further improvements to the usability etc.

Within your BjyAuthorize configuration you just configure what each Role can see/access/edit etc. and you should be good to go.

Comment: I disagree with you on "no you shouldn't create modules for each of these users". I think it entirely depends on the project.

Comment: Can i use the diffrent layout for the different user, in the single module?

Comment: @AlexP Now that you mention it you are 100% correct. I didnt think as far as to having entire diffrent functionality.

Comment: @mark_winkle yes. I personally didnt use any modules or had to alter the layout depending on the user role but there is a module I have seen being used https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts . But then again you could just write it yourself. Either provide each module a new layout or change it depending on the user role.